# Using media query min-width for mobile breakpoints

Tags: css, less

I'm attempting a mobile first layout using media queries with min-width requirements. Is the only way to achieve "greater than but NOT equal to" a min width by adding 1? That seems unintuitive to me, as I am storing my breakpoint values in LESS variables, and would like the actual breakpoint to be stored without the plus one.

```
@mobile-breakpoint: 361px;
// breakpoint is actually at 360px

@media (min-width: @mobile-breakpoint) {
    //styles for widths greater than but not equal to 360
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use calc function in your media queries to add 1px in multiple breakpoints

```
@mobile-breakpoint: 360px;

@media (min-width: calc(@mobile-breakpoint + 1px)) {
    //styles for widths greater than but not equal to 360
}
```

Unfortunately we don't have any other simple ways to get the exact greater than method in media queries

### The LESS way:-

As seven-phases-max mentioned we can achieve the same using `LESS` way by simply adding `+1`  like

```
@mobile-breakpoint: 360px;

@media (min-width: (@mobile-breakpoint + 1)) {
    foo {bar: baz}
}
```

Comment: If it's about Less then `calc` is redundant in this case - just `min-width: (@mobile-breakpoint + 1)` [does the trick](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40mobile-breakpoint%3A%20360px%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40media%20(min-width%3A%20(%40mobile-breakpoint%20%2B%201))%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20foo%20%7Bbar%3A%20baz%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D). (More over, technically `calc` is not really supported in media queries per CSS specs).